# Need to join the elements of a list but keep the '' around element after joining

Tags: python, python-2.7

my list is:

```
example = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If I use  `",".join(example)` ,  removes `' '` around the elements.

I want my output to be:

```
example = "'a','b','c'"
```

Any elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's elegant, but it works (based on the default representation of `list` objects and therefore not flexible at all):

```
>>> example = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> repr(example)[1:-1] # [1:-1] to remove brackets
"'a', 'b', 'c'"
```

Another one (easily customizable):

```
>>> example = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> "'{joined}'".format(joined="', '".join(example))
"'a', 'b', 'c'"
```

Something like this was already suggested by others, but still:

```
>>> example = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ', '.join([repr(x) for x in example])
"'a', 'b', 'c'"
```

Comment: Your second solution is actually the fastest one of all the proposed solutions so far. I think @imiu deserves a few more upvotes for his question giving us something interesting to discuss.

Comment: @TimPietzcker and the first one is twice as slow as the second.

Answer (score 3):

```
','.join(map(repr,example))
Out[74]: "'a','b','c'"
```

Comment: +1, although I'd use a generator expression `",".join(repr(item) for item in example)` instead of `map()`.

Comment: IIRC `str.join` actually works better on materialized lists rather than on gen expressions.

Comment: @TimPietzcker `.join` needs a total size of a submitted iterable to allocate memory for a new string *before* the joining process starts, so it will firstly unroll the generator.

Comment: @frostnational, roippi: That makes sense, thanks! I've added a CW answer with some timings. The `map()` approach is still the fastest, even though Guido would have liked to remove it from the language in favor of listcomps/genexps. Interesting.

Comment: Thak you all! This is my first time posting a question here but you got me hooked! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just a few timings:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = 'example = list("abcdefghijklmnop")'
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt = '",".join(repr(item) for item in example)')
4.316254299507404
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt = '",".join([repr(item) for item in example])')
3.393636402412758
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt = '",".join(map(repr, example))')
3.2305143115811887
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt = '''"'{joined}'".format(joined="','".join(example))''')
1.308451301197806
```