# How to remove square brackts and single quotes from a list using python?

Tags: python

I have a list looks like below

```
 list_val = ['1','2','3','4']
```

I want to remove the square bracket and single quotes from the list. I like to get the output as like below

```
list_new = 1,2,3,4
```

Is it possible? Looking forward for quick help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of (or very similar to) [Need to join the elements of a list but keep the '' around element after joining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458448/need-to-join-the-elements-of-a-list-but-keep-the-around-element-after-joining)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The square brackets and commas are the syntax for list literals, the quotes are the syntax for string literals. You can get `[1, 2, 3, 4]` by making the list elements integers. Without square brackets, it's a tuple, not a list. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought the expected result was a new list having integer value of list_val but expected answer was to just print string format `list_new = 1,2,3,4` which makes no sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For output, don't use the Python **repr**-esentation. Here, use join:

```
list_val = ['1','2','3','4']
print 'list_new = %s' % ','.join(list_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
list_new = [int(x) for x in list_val]
```

Comment: @@user590028: I tried list_new = [int(x) for x in list_val] but I got this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'halloo'

Comment: @questionspost that looks nothing like the example in your question - you might want to update it to be more representative of real data

Answer (score 0):

```
list_new = 1,2,3,4
```

This expression is equivalent to [**`tuple assignment`**](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html#tuple-assignment).

```
>>> list_val = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> list_new = tuple(map(lambda x:int(x), list_val))
>>> list_new
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Is equivalent to :

```
>>> list_new = 1, 2, 3, 4
>>> list_new
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```